# Change the decimal and thousands separators in a GeoServer SLD styled map

Tags: geoserver, sld

I didn't find a way to change the decimal and thousands separators in the SLD style of map in my GeoServer. The Server (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS), Tomcat (9.0.31), JVM (Ubuntu: 11.0.13 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) and GeoServer (2.18.0) locale is the right one (es_ES), but when i use the function  `numberFormat` the labels appears with "," as the thousand separator and "." as a decimal separator.
After a week of searching the only workaround I found whas use the function  `strReplace` to change manually.
Someone knows a better way?

PS: Here is a copy of the first draft of the solution

```
<ogc:Function name="strReplace">
  <!-- string:String - Number in en_US locale -->  
  <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
    <ogc:Literal>###,###,###</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:PropertyName>poblacion</ogc:PropertyName>
  </ogc:Function>
  <!-- pattern:String  - Regexp of value to change-->
  <ogc:Literal>\,</ogc:Literal>
  <!-- replacement:String - New value -->
  <ogc:Literal>.</ogc:Literal>
  <!-- global: boolean - Regexp global parameter-->
  <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a check of the [source code for the `numberFormat` code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/0d475aea085891ae470eeb71fdd5b0aba20f947f/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/FilterFunction_numberFormat.java#L89) I can see there is an optional third argument to set the locale to be used.

So with the following style, my map goes from the one on the left/top (no locale provided, so the [default `English` one](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/0d475aea085891ae470eeb71fdd5b0aba20f947f/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/FilterFunction_numberFormat.java#L43)), to the one the right/below:

```
        <Label>
          <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
            <ogc:Literal>###,###,###</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>es</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Label>
```

[image: UK locale] [image: ES locale]

To be honest I have no clue as to why we picked an English locale as the default rather than the local machine's locale. It is probably related to making tests pass on machines around the world. I've made an [enhancement request](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7087) to honour the locale of the machine and to add the option to set it to the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#parsing-and-formatting-functions).

Answer (score 3):

Since around 2016, you can specify the language you want as a third parameter:

```
<ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
  <ogc:Literal>###,###,###</ogc:Literal>
  <ogc:PropertyName>poblacion</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Literal>en</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
```

Comment: did you add that option with out updating the docs?

Comment: whoops, just did a `git blame` and it was me 5 years ago though I have no memory of it

Comment: LOL, yep, I noticed too.